# Solve the first order Non-homogenous differential equation, $(x +3y - 4)dx + (x + 4y - 5)dy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A hint is given: Put $x = X + h$ & $y = Y + k$ then $h = 1, k = 1$.

And the final solution is also given which is given as
$$(x - 1)^4 + 4(x - 1)^3 (y - 1) + 4(y - 1)^2 (x - 1)^2 = K$$

I have tried solving it (attached below) but I am not able to get to the final solution as given above.

[Answer Page 1 Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIjgi.jpg)

[Answer Page 2 Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp1e5.jpg)

[Answer Page 3 Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34ywz.jpg)

Comment: Please use MathJax ([tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1)) and avoid using pictures. Such practices invite downvotes even if your question is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x +3y - 4)dx + (x + 4y - 5)dy=0$$
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=-\dfrac {(x +3y - 4)}{ (x + 4y - 5)}$$
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=-\dfrac {(x \color {red}{-1} +3y \color {red}{ - 3})}{ (x  \color {red}{-1} + 4y  \color {red}{- 4})}$$
$$\dfrac {dY}{dX}=-\dfrac {X +3Y}{ X + 4Y}$$
Substitute:
$$Y=TX \implies Y'=T'X+T$$
The differential equation is homogeneous.
$$T'X+T=-\dfrac {3T+1}{ 4T+1}$$
$$T'X+=-\dfrac {(2T+1)^2}{ 4T+1}$$
$$\int \dfrac { 4T+1}{(2T+1)^2} \, dT=-\int \dfrac {dX}{X}$$
After integration we have:
$$\ln |2Y+X|+\dfrac {X}{4Y+2X}=C$$
Where $y-1=Y$ and $x-1=X$.

The answer provided seems not correct to me.

Comment: That's great @PrateekArora ...

Comment: Yup, I did take it from there and got

$$ \frac {1 - x} {2(2y + x - 3)} - ln( 2y + x - 3) = C $$

But the final answer is this,

$$ (x−1)4+4(x−1)3(y−1)+4(y−1)2(x−1)2=K $$

(My workings are attached in the pictures above)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The answer provided is worng the answer must involve a log function or an exponential at least. @PrateekArora

Comment: Alrighty, thanks bro!

Comment: You're welcome @PrateekArora

Comment: I added my final answer and as yours it also involves a log function. @PrateekArora